# React - setState on input field not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seem to be missing something, why is the setState not working for me?!
If i pull the initial state into value of the text input field to make it controlled, the setState does not work for me...what am I doing wrong?

```
      class Module extends Component {
          constructor() {
              super()

              this.state = {
                  text: 'text'
              }

              this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
          }

          handleInputChange(event) {
              console.log('handle input change')
              this.setState = ({
                  text: 'new state: ' + event.target.value
              })
              console.log(event.target.value)
          }

          render() {
              return (
                  <div>
                      <input
                          type="text"
                          value={ this.state.text }
                          onChange={ this.handleInputChange }
                      />
                  </div>
              )
          }
      }

      export default Module
```

Comment: It's just a typo. `this.setState = ({` should be function call not assignment `this.setState({`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you sooo much! Thought I'm going crazy...time for a break I guess

Answer (score 8):

Because `setState` is asynchronous. But fortunately there is a callback parameter in the method call which you can use to get the value like this

```
    this.setState({
        text: 'new state: ' + event.target.value
    }, () => {
        console.log(text)
    })
```

Btw you are not assigning anything to `setState` it's a method call. 
Besides that since `events` are synthetic events in React you have to store the current target in a variable to not lose the event for example like this

```
    const saveValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        text: 'new state: ' + saveValue 
    });
    console.log(saveValue);
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with async nature of `setState` per se. OP does not manually read state.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes I realized that. That's why there is a second part to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Store the changed value, `setState()` is asynchronous.

```
handleInputChange(event) {
  const myValue = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    text: myValue
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have 'new state: ' in the setState? The onChange function is called on every key press or change, so you shouldn't add your own text inside of the setState function. If you wanna use ES6, you can change the onChange call to:

```
(event) => this.handleInputChange(event.target.value)
```

and the handleInput function to:

```
handleInputChange(value) {
  this.setState({
    text: value
  })
}
```

If you need the 'new state: ' string before the input text then put it inside of a span before the input instead.

Comment: This answer doesn't address original question and contains the same typo.