# setState is not working when i try to store select value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

react.js setState is not working properly.
when I select "Full", "Middle" and "Large" from selection and store it to state.size on hanleChange, Its not working .
what i want is when i select something from 'select' it should store event.target.value to state.size, but its not reflecting the change.
code is not properly [image]
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './write.scss';
import ArticlePoster from '../../image/moon.jpg';

class PosterSize extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            size: "Medium",
            posterDiv: "700px",
        }
    }
    handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log("the value is " + event.target.value);
        this.setState({ size: event.target.value });
        console.log("size = " + this.state.size);
        if (this.state.size === "Medium") {
            this.setState({ posterDiv: "700px" });
            console.log(this.state.size, this.state.posterDiv);
        }
        else if (this.state.size === "Full") {
            this.setState({ posterDiv: "100%" });
            console.log(this.state.size, this.state.posterDiv);
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ posterDiv: "800px" });
            console.log(this.state.size, this.state.posterDiv);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="mn-wrt">
                <div><h1>Your title goes here.</h1></div>
                <div
                    className="mn-wrt-poster-div"
                    style={
                        {
                            width: this.state.posterDiv
                        }
                    }
                >
                    <img src={ArticlePoster} alt="article poster" className="mn-wrt-poster" />
                    <div className="mn-wrt-poster-select">
                        <label>
                            Pick size
                        <select value={this.state.size} onChange={this.handleChange}>            
                                <option value="Full">Full</option>
                                <option value="Large">Large</option>
                                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default PosterSize;
```

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, so it won't be updated by the next line in your JS code. Instead, it'll be available in your _next render_ of the component. You should see it correctly in the rendered content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - setState on input field not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046897/react-setstate-on-input-field-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply because `setState` is asynchronous, so it takes a moment to update. You can pass a handler function as a second argumento to setState, which will run *after* the state has updated, like so:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log("the value is " + event.target.value);

        // Pass an arrow function as second parameter
        this.setState({ size: event.target.value }, () => { 

          console.log("size = " + this.state.size); //updated state with new value

          if (this.state.size === "Medium") {
            this.setState({ posterDiv: "700px" });
            console.log(this.state.size, this.state.posterDiv);
          }
          else if (this.state.size === "Full") {
            this.setState({ posterDiv: "100%" });
            console.log(this.state.size, this.state.posterDiv);
          }
          else {
             this.setState({ posterDiv: "800px" });
             console.log(this.state.size, this.state.posterDiv);
          }
        });
    
    };
```